# Application error after successful upload to appstore

Tags: alamofire

We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for "App Name". To process your delivery, the following issues must be corrected:

Invalid Bundle - One or more dynamic libraries that are referenced by your app are not present in the dylib search path.

Once these issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the corrected binary.

Regards,
Note : in project is using : Libaries: Alamofire 3.0

The App Store team

Help me!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm stuck with the same error.